# assigning values to multiple js objects from the same form in a DRY fashion on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making typing game. Up to 4 players can play the game. Here's the html.

```
<!-- Avatar Select -->
<div class="select container col-sm-6" id="avatar">
  <h4 id="playerSelector">Player 1</h4>
  <h4>Please enter your name.</h4>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="playerName">
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="submitPlayer">Submit</button>

</div>
```

I want to save each persons name, and eventually an avatar and a score to each player object. I thought the below function would do it. But it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //define players
  var player1 = {
    name: "player 1",
    avatar: "",
    score: 0,
  }
  var player2 = {
    name: "player 2",
    avatar: "",
    score: 0,
  }
```

... there's 2 more, but I skipped them

```
  //submit player info button
  var playerNum = 1;
  var tempPlayer = "";
  $("#submitPlayer").on("click", function () {
    tempPlayer = "player" + playerNum;
    tempPlayer.name = $("#playerName").val();
    playerNum += 1;
    if (playerNum > numPlayers) {
      $("#avatar").hide();
      $("#instructions").show();
    } else {
      return
    }
  });

});
```

when i console log it, tempPlayer looks correct, it is the same string as the variable player1, but when I try to set it to the value of the input box it doesn't take it. I'm assuming this is because it's looking for an object of the name tempPlayer as opposed to player1, even though at this point tempPlayer is the same string player1. Is this true? And if so, what's a method that would achieve the same action without having to write a function for each player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSON object to achieve this, and your code will look something like the below

```
var jsonArr = [];
 $("#submitPlayer").on("click", function () {
jsonArr.push({
    name: $("#playerName").val();,
    avatar: '',
    ... //other values
});
});
```

you will need to tweak it so that it only works 4 times and things like that. The main reason that your above doesnt work is because it is not possible to concatenate string to create a pre defined variable in JS.